# Hibernate Entities generated using IntelliJ have no Foreign Keys generated

Tags: hibernate, database, sql-server, intellij-idea

I have a normalized SQL Server database with 20+ tables on it that created using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I am able to connect to this database in IntelliJ and follow along with the steps outlined in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnQ_4cLe7Qg

However, when the entities are actually generated, there are no foreign key relationships in the entities (i.e. no @Join or @ManyToOne annotations anywhere) even though IntelliJ clearly recognizes all of these FK relationships when I do a right-click->Diagrams->Show Visualization on my database from the IntelliJ Database Tool Window (i.e. the arrows get drawn between each connected table in the resulting diagram).

I AM checking the box marked "Show Default Relationships" as I have read on this page:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/import-database-schema-import-mappings.html

...that "If this check box is selected, IntelliJ IDEA analyzes foreign keys in the tables and suggests to create corresponding relationships."

Isn't there a way to just have all the foreign keys created for me automatically?

Comment: Add to you question sql script with DB statements and FK constraints.

Comment: Hi Anton, this question applies to any database design / set of FK constraints.  I am just trying to generate the Hibernate annotations that a decent IDE should generate automatically.  Any ideas how this can be done?  I think even Eclipse is better in this regard, but IntelliJ is much easier to work with overall so I prefer to use IntelliJ.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in IDEA 15, relationships and foreign keys mapping work fine in IDEA 14.

Comment: Yes, I think this a bug in IDEA 15. I generate my entities and relationships in IDEA 13 without any problem but it doesn't work in IDEA 15!!!

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me. I thought I was going insane because I remember when this used to work.

Comment: @kevingreen - My brother from another mother...

Comment: @RyanAtwood I ended up using NetBeans to reverse engineer, then copied the files into my IntelliJ solution. I hope this is a good short term fix. But now my PHP editor stopped working in IntelliJ after today's update. GET IT TOGETHER JETBRAINS!